# Java Spring Hibernate Schema-Validation: Missing Table

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

Having a very weird issue here. I have a list of environments built for dev/test/qa/prod. Each connects to a different database, one corresponding to each environment. When I run the code in dev, everything is great, when I run it in any other environment, I get

```
Factory method 'sessionFactory' threw exception; nested exception is org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementException: Schema-validation: missing table [dbo.Cause_Code]
```

I would like to now note that this for test/qa/prod, the code is deployed to servers and WORKS. No errors, but running it locally gives me that missing table. That table definately exists and dev/test/qa/prod databases are in the exact same schema state.

You can see here that the table is in the QA database and the IDE sees that:
[image]

Adding schema="dbo" to table annotation does nothing, changing hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto to none allows it to build, but all calls fail for the same reason.

I should note that I have tested that is not the environments I built. Dev works, I changed the database connection for that environment to QA and it failed. I also tried adding in the data source directly to hibernate persistance window and that did nothing.

Can someone tell me why the IDE thinks the tabble doesn't exist, but the deployed code works great and the table definitely exists? I have to be missing a simple setting somewhere.

Comment: I had to connect to my old SQL server db once, and I don't remember I had to add the "dbo" onto the mapping. I think you should check your connection string carefully.

Comment: Exact same connection string used in the db viewer as in the connection. Re-installing the IDE and importing the shared environment with no changes worked. Looks like it was a bad file somewhere in the IDE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I got tired of trying different things over the last 6 hours and re-installed the IDE. Imported the project which had the shared environment configs already set up. Made no changes and just ran the QA build, worked first try. I guess there was something messed up in the install. No idea why it only affected every environment but dev though. I tried everything form restarting the entire computer to disabling everything to creating an empty project and only the re-install fixed it.